# prove\disprove - there are functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ such that $g(n) = o(1)$ and $f(n-g(n)) \neq \Theta((f(n))$

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

there are functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ such that  $g(n) = o(1)$ and $f(n-g(n)) \neq \Theta((f(n))$

Thought about $f(n) = |sin(n)|,\  g(n)= \frac1n$ then $f(n-g(n))= |sin(n-\frac1n)|$ and then for any $n_0\geq0,\  c>0$ there is an $n>n_0$ but $f(n-g(n)) > c\cdot f(n)$ so for $n=2\pi n_0$ will get  $ |sin(2\pi n_0-\frac1{\pi n_0)})|>  c\cdot|sin(2\pi n_0)| = 0$

but i think $f$ should be a positive function $>0$.

need to prove\disprove with that definition.

Comment: Hint: consider an $f$ that grows fast enough for even 'minute' perturbations to overwhelm.  You might look at functions of the form $f(n) = 2^{\left(n^k\right)}$ for various values of $k$, and see what evaluating at $n-\frac1n$ does to them...

Comment: thanks! $2^{((n-{\frac{1} {n})}^3)} = o(2^{(n^3)})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a hint from Steven Stadnicki, an example was found: $g(n)=1/n$, $f(n)=2^{n^3}$. Indeed, 
$$f(n-g(n))=2^{(n-1/n)^3} = 2^{n^3-3n+3/n-1/n^3} =\Theta(2^{n^3-3n})=o(2^{n^3})$$